# Which qualities should I look for in a driveway sealer for new asphalt?

Tags: sealing, driveway

Two years ago, the blacktop on my driveway was replaced.  It has never been sealed. The local hardware and paint stores sell various driveway sealers.

What features should I look for when I buy sealer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for two things: 1) wear surface, and 2) adhesion.

1) Wear surface: There's always good-better-and best in all things. Asphalt coatings are no different. Asphalt coatings are a oil-based product and wear has to do with particles in the compound (liquid). When oil is "refined", it has chemicals and particles that can be used for asphalt coatings, roofing, etc. (How it's refined give you the good-better-and best results. I don't know how to determine which is best, but see item 2), below.)

2) Adhesion: Look for a coating with a "gel base", not a "latex base". Gels flow, coat and adhere better. (Btw, the warranty is longer with gels too. I think warranties are 3-5 years with latex and 7-8 years with gels.)

Btw, you said you have NEW asphalt. Do not coat or seal it until it's "cured"...about 6 months. Follow the directions...clean, apply at correct temperature, etc.

Comment: Is "Epoxy" gel?  E.g., https://www.amazon.com/RUST-OLEUM-247471-Epoxy-Blacktop-Coating/dp/B0029TB1B2/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1502310615&sr=8-4-fkmr0&keywords=gel+asphalt+sealer

Comment: IDK...I've never used Rust-Oleum...

Comment: I have tried 2 large hardware stores and neither has heard of gel based driveway sealer.  Does it go by another name?

Answer (score 2):

Attached is picture of sealer I found at local Ace Hardware store. Please note on third line down, on the red can, it refers to "gel" technology. You may want to get ahold of the manufacturer and have them "explain" what gel is...

The green can is cheaper, but is not as good. [image]

[image]

[image]